# Is it possible to create a function using R code from outside of R?

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have an R script saved in a notepad file in a .txt format (e.g. examples.txt). This file contains many "chunks" of codes, for example:

```
#chunk 1
    c = b+a

#chunk 2
    d = c - b

# chunk 3
    e = c*d
```

[image]

Suppose I open a new R session - in this new R session, I create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)
my_df = data.frame(a = rnorm(10,10,10), b=rnorm(10,10,10))
```

**My Question:** After my_df has been created, is it possible to execute the .txt file for each row of my_df?

In the end, the final result would look something like this:

```
           a         b         c         d          e index
1   4.395244 22.240818  26.63606  4.395244  117.07198     1
2   7.698225 13.598138  21.29636  7.698225  163.94420     2
3  25.587083 14.007715  39.59480 25.587083 1013.11538     3
4  10.705084 11.106827  21.81191 10.705084  233.49834     4
5  11.292877  4.441589  15.73447 11.292877  177.68739     5
6  27.150650 27.869131  55.01978 27.150650 1493.82282     6
7  14.609162 14.978505  29.58767 14.609162  432.25102     7
8  -2.650612 -9.666172 -12.31678 -2.650612   32.64702     8
9   3.131471 17.013559  20.14503  3.131471   63.08359     9
10  5.543380  5.272086  10.81547  5.543380   59.95424    10
```

Thanks!

**References:**

- [R: Automatically Running R Scripts from TXT files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75513243/r-automatically-running-r-scripts-from-txt-files)

**Notes:**

- c,d,e are NOT being saved as functions. If c,d,e were functions - this would have been much easier.

Comment: hi stats_noob! How would the new environment know what `b` and `a` are? When I run `source("examples.txt")`, I get Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'b' not found

Comment: @Mark: thank you for your reply! the environment would know a,b by the following a = my_df[1,1], my_df[1,2]

Comment: also would you like me to add an index in the answer, or would you like it to be in the question, or does it not matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rarely used function [`within`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/with) may make this a lot easier:

```
set.seed(123)
my_df = data.frame(a = rnorm(10,10,10), b=rnorm(10,10,10))

my_df <-
    within(my_df, sys.source("examples.txt",envir=environment()))

my_df
```

It lets the code in examples.txt see the columns of your data.frame as variables. This solution also lets you source the code without use of `eval()` or any other manual handling of code evaluation.

Output:

```
           a         b          e         d         c
1   4.395244 22.240818  117.07198  4.395244  26.63606
2   7.698225 13.598138  163.94420  7.698225  21.29636
3  25.587083 14.007715 1013.11538 25.587083  39.59480
4  10.705084 11.106827  233.49834 10.705084  21.81191
5  11.292877  4.441589  177.68739 11.292877  15.73447
6  27.150650 27.869131 1493.82282 27.150650  55.01978
7  14.609162 14.978505  432.25102 14.609162  29.58767
8  -2.650612 -9.666172   32.64702 -2.650612 -12.31678
9   3.131471 17.013559   63.08359  3.131471  20.14503
10  5.543380  5.272086   59.95424  5.543380  10.81547
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! we don't need to specify that the R code in examples.txt need to be run on every row?

Comment: suppose there are some intermediate errors in "examples.txt" ... is it somehow possible to force  sys.source() to skip those errors and continue?

Comment: Just be warned that, should you start writing things to `.GlobalEnv`, you'll be violating one of the "rules" of safe programming (and CRAN will reject any submissions that do so).  You really don't want to write to the top-level environment's objects because that risks letting a function foul up things outside it's "purview."

Comment: @Carl: thank you for your reply! I posted a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893994/r-forcing-sys-source-to-skip-errors - is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @Carl, in case you are refering to the use of sys.source, I explicitly tell it what environment to write to (and it is not .GlobalEnv)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (though I'm not sure this is what you had in mind):

```
library(tidyverse)

a = my_df$a
b = my_df$b
source("examples.txt")
mutate(my_df, c = c, d = d, e = e)
```

Here's another method:

```
mutation <- readLines("examples.txt") %>%
              str_subset("^\\s+[a-z]") %>%
              paste0(collapse = ", ") %>% 
              {paste0("mutate(my_df, ", ., ")")}

eval(parse(mutation))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! can you please explain how the first answer works? what is source() doing?

Comment: `source()` came from the answer you linked! ^_^

Comment: *source causes R to accept its input from the named file or URL or connection or expressions directly. Input is read and parsed from that file until the end of the file is reached, then the parsed expressions are evaluated sequentially in the chosen environment.* [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/source)

Comment: @stats_noob if you type `?source` in the R terminal, or point to the function with your cursor and press F1, you should get the function help file. It's all there.

Comment: Sorry, i should have made myself more clear

Comment: What i meant was - is source() loading the functions into R permanently or temporarily?

Comment: I think what you're asking is very similar/the same question as, "what environment does source() run the file in? To which the answer appears to be the global environment, unless you specify otherwise

Comment: @mark: thank you so much for all your clarifications. I have posted a related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893994/r-forcing-sys-source-to-skip-errors ... do you think this is possible?

Comment: @Mark: I am trying to use the methodology in this question alongside this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896022/r-completely-suppressing-errors .... do you have any idea why this code runs even though it produces errors?

Comment: @stats_noob re: the second one - I don't have a huge amount of experience with RSelenium, so I wouldn't feel confident shooting from the hip, so to speak. My go to with these things is to load everything into RStudio, then run debug() on the function I'm looking at, and inspect various objects, to see if they are what I expect them to be. Though I'm sure you are experienced enough to know of these things, so me saying them is redundant haha

Answer (score 1):

You can use base R functions to accomplish the same:

```
within(my_df, eval(str2expression(readLines('examples.txt'))))
```