# R: Forcing sys.source() to skip errors

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

In a previous question ([Is it possible to create a function using R code from outside of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891763/is-it-possible-to-create-a-function-using-r-code-from-outside-of-r)), I learned how to use the `sys.source()` function to execute an R code within a txt notepad file on inputs within the local environment.

**Now I have the following question:**

Suppose I have the following dataframe created in R:

```
set.seed(123)
my_df = data.frame(a = rnorm(10,10,10), b=rnorm(10,10,10))
```

And suppose the  txt (examples.txt) file has some errors within the file:

[image]

```
#examples.txt

#chunk 1
    c = b+a

#chunk 2
    d = c - b

#error
d a

# chunk 3
    e = c -a
```

**Is it possible to specifically modify the `sys.source()` function (while keeping the txt file as is) to keep running even though the errors have been encountered?**

```
my_df <- within(my_df, sys.source("examples.txt",envir=environment()))

Error in parse(n = -1, file = file, srcfile = NULL, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  10:3: unexpected symbol
9: 
10: d a
      ^
```

Thanks!

**Notes:**

- I know I can use `tryCatch()` in the txt file itself... but I specifically want to use it within the `sys.source()` function.
- This is because my real notepad txt file has many lines of R code - all these lines run successfully but somehow still produce errors.
- It would take a lot of time to modify the notepad file directly and add `tryCath()` statements throughout the notepad file
- Thus, I am trying to modify the `sys.source()` function such that it can continue running the notepad txt file even when it encounters errors

Comment: I suppose you could take each line, and wrap it in a tryCatch()

Comment: @Mark: thank you for your reply! I know I can use tryCatch() in the txt file itself... but I specifically want to use it within the sys.source() function. is this possible?

Comment: I can't see anything about it looking in the documentation for it... would map work okay for you?

Comment: @Mark: thank you for your reply! how do you think  map() can be used here? btw I added some updates in the notes section to better explain my problem

Comment: I recomend you first try to figure out why there's an unexpected error in your code

Comment: @ Sirius: thank you for your reply! I have posted the exact errors here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896022/r-completely-suppressing-errors

Comment: @stats_noob on second thought, I have no clue how that would work (map with source)! but you could get something similar by creating your own function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

@Nicola gave a very valuable hint about using the `n` parameter in `parse` which leads to another strategy, instead of reading lines (`<>`expressions)  we tell `parse` straight away to use one expression at a time. So line breaks are not an issue anymore. (in all due respect, @Nicola should be the one credited with the right answer)

---

I would parse each line of `example.txt` and if the parsing works (i.e. no syntax error), add it to an expression. Thus, you are filtering faulty lines and then you can use `eval` on the working expression:

```r
ex_fn <- "example.txt"

####################################################################################
## set up example
cat(c("#examples.txt", "", "#chunk 1", "c = b+a", "", "#chunk 2", 
      "d = c - b", "", "#error", "d a", "", "# chunk 3", "e = c -a"),
    sep = "\n",
    file = ex_fn)
####################################################################################


## Parse file
fh <- file(ex_fn, "r")
exs <- expression()
eof <- FALSE
while (!eof) {
   ex <- try({
      pex <- parse(fh, 1L)
      exs <<- c(exs, pex)
      pex
      }, silent = FALSE) ## change to TRUE if you do not care about being notified
   eof <- !length(ex)
}
close(fh)
exs

## Test
set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 10, 10), b = rnorm(10, 10, 10))

## throws error
# within(my_df, sys.source(ex_fn, envir = environment()))
# Error in parse(n = -1, file = file, srcfile = NULL, keep.source = FALSE) : 
#   10:3: unexpected symbol
# 9: #error
# 10: d a
#       ^

## works
within(my_df, eval(exs, envir = environment()))
#            a         b         e         d         c
# 1   4.395244 22.240818 22.240818  4.395244  26.63606
# 2   7.698225 13.598138 13.598138  7.698225  21.29636
# 3  25.587083 14.007715 14.007715 25.587083  39.59480
# 4  10.705084 11.106827 11.106827 10.705084  21.81191
# 5  11.292877  4.441589  4.441589 11.292877  15.73447
# 6  27.150650 27.869131 27.869131 27.150650  55.01978
# 7  14.609162 14.978505 14.978505 14.609162  29.58767
# 8  -2.650612 -9.666172 -9.666172 -2.650612 -12.31678
# 9   3.131471 17.013559 17.013559  3.131471  20.14503
# 10  5.543380  5.272086  5.272086  5.543380  10.81547
```

Comment: Why is the tempfile needed? If they have already parsed the code, couldn't OP just `eval` that?

Comment: Your code is already parsing. There is no reason to create the tempfile and parse again. See my answer.

Comment: Ah now I got your question, the tempfile is just simply for convenience to have a file with the cleaned code. But what is substantially different in your answer as compared to mine? just to group code between code blocks?

Comment: The main issue I guess it's the same I outlined in Roland's answer: a line of text and a line of code are very different concepts. Just use `parse(..., n=1)` with a connection to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, your design is doomed. You should fix the process that creates broken code.

However, as @nicola points out, you can specify how many expressions `parse` should parse, which is useful here.

```
ex_fn <- "D:/temp/example.txt"

## set up example
cat(c("#examples.txt", "", "#chunk 1", "c = b+a", "", "#chunk 2", 
      "d = c - b", "", "#error", "d a", "", "# chunk 3", "e = c -a"),
    sep = "\n",
    file = ex_fn)


f <- file(ex_fn, "r")

#parse code with error catcher, 
#n = 1L is the max number of expressions to parse,
#parse increments to the next expression after each call
expr <- list()
i <- 1L

repeat {
  expr[[i]] <- tryCatch(parse(f, n = 1L), error = \(e) NA)
  if (identical(expr[[i]], expression())) {
    expr <- expr[-i]
    break
  }
  i <- i + 1L
}

close(f)

set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 10, 10), b = rnorm(10, 10, 10))

#evaluate parsed code    
within(my_df, lapply(expr, eval, envir = environment()))
#            a         b         e         d         c
# 1   4.395244 22.240818 22.240818  4.395244  26.63606
# 2   7.698225 13.598138 13.598138  7.698225  21.29636
# 3  25.587083 14.007715 14.007715 25.587083  39.59480
# 4  10.705084 11.106827 11.106827 10.705084  21.81191
# 5  11.292877  4.441589  4.441589 11.292877  15.73447
# 6  27.150650 27.869131 27.869131 27.150650  55.01978
# 7  14.609162 14.978505 14.978505 14.609162  29.58767
# 8  -2.650612 -9.666172 -9.666172 -2.650612 -12.31678
# 9   3.131471 17.013559 17.013559  3.131471  20.14503
# 10  5.543380  5.272086  5.272086  5.543380  10.81547
```

Comment: There is I think a big improvement in your answer if you make use of the `n` argument of `parse` after opening a connection of the file. Something like `f<-file("example.R","r")` and then in a loop `parse(f,n=1)` wrapped by `tryCatch` and the logic you described.

Comment: @nicola Thanks, I changed the answer accordingly.